# Solvers in CVXPy seem to be sensitive to initial conditions, imprecise, or incompatible

Tags: precision, solver, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I've recently implemented a convex program from my research in CVXPy and I'm not reliably getting good answers. By this I mean that when I use:

1. ECOS sometimes I get an answer and other times I get "Unreliable search direction detected, recovering best iterate (18) and stopping.
   NUMERICAL PROBLEMS (reached feastol=1.6e-07, reltol=-nan, abstol=1.8e-04)." When trying to isolate the problem I hardcoded everything before the solver and then just kept rerunning until it worked (i.e. run the code->Yay answer->run->error->run->error->run->Yay answer), so I'm assuming it has something to do with the initial conditions the solver uses? Its super annoying that it doesn't work consistently, but when ECOS works I get a great picture perfect answer. Also, this seems to happen more often when I run my bigger examples.
2. SCS I always get an answer, but it isn't super precise (e.g. one of the constraints in the program says variables should be non-negative, but I'll get -.00057). Honestly, it isn't the worst thing in the world but it'd make me fell much better if I could increase the accuracy (this inaccuracy happens even on small examples that ECOS crushes).
3. CVXOPT just gives me "cvxpy.error.SolverError: Either candidate conic solvers (['CVXOPT']) do not support the cones output by the problem (SOC, ExpCone), or there are not enough constraints in the problem."

I'm totally new to using these solvers, so any advice or explanations would be super helpful. I'd even be open to having ECOS try over and over until something gave.

Thanks!

Comment: This is too broad. Show some code/model and be more clear about your iterating hardcoding process which lead to solutions as this sounds strange. Ecos should be deterministic, at least in serial mode.

Comment: Dupin, thanks for your question. You should try using the MOSEK solver. It is substantially more reliable and accurate than ECOS and SCS. MOSEK is a commercial solver, but academics may use it for free. CVXPY supports MOSEK, but you’ll need to install the solver separately. Here’s their website: https://www.mosek.com/

Comment: Additionally, you can pass extra solver-specifc arguments to the solve method. For example, problem.solve(solver=cp.SCS, eps=1e-10). (The extra arguments are documented on the CVXPY website.)